# local variable 'B' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
def fun(p,q,x=x):
    p=p*x^0
    q=q*x^0
    t=diff(q)
    u=p.degree(x)+1
    s=p.degree(x)-t.degree(x)
    o=s+1
    if s<0:
        print('The integral does not undertake in elementary functions')
    else:
        if s==0:
            A=var('A0')
        else:
            A=var(['A%d' %n for n in range(o)])
            r=sum([A[i]*(x^i) for i in range(o)])
            h=diff(r,x)+r*diff(q,x)-p
            l=diff(r,x)+r*diff(q,x)
            B=([l.coefficient(x,n) for n in range(u)])
            C=([p.coefficient(x,n) for n in range(u)])
        if o==1:
            t=solve((B[u-1]-C[u-1]==0),r)
            r=r.subs(t)
            print(r)
        else:
            z=[h.subs(x=n)==0 for n in range(u)]
            t=solve(z,A)
            l=len(t[0])
        if t[0][l-1]!=0:
            r=r.subs(t)
            print(r)
        else:
            print('The integral does not undertake in elementary functions')
```

Не выводит fun(x,x**2). Знаю что ошибка в области видимости, но не получается исправить.

Comment: При `s==0` и `o==1` - переменная `B` используется, но еще не определена

Comment: не надо повторяться http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/607684/217000

Answer (score 1):

Предположите ситуацию: если s == 0, тогда o = s+1 = 1.

Тогда из этого фрагмента

```
    if s==0:
        A=var('A0')
    else:
        A=var(['A%d' %n for n in range(o)])
        r=sum([A[i]*(x^i) for i in range(o)])
        h=diff(r,x)+r*diff(q,x)-p
        l=diff(r,x)+r*diff(q,x)
        B=([l.coefficient(x,n) for n in range(u)])
        C=([p.coefficient(x,n) for n in range(u)])
```

выполнится первая ветка. И при этом, переменная B не будет инициализирована.

Далее в логике условий

```
    if o==1:
        t=solve((B[u-1]-C[u-1]==0),r)
        r=r.subs(t)
        print(r)
    else:
        z=[h.subs(x=n)==0 for n in range(u)]
        t=solve(z,A)
        l=len(t[0])
```

Выполнится также первая ветка условия. И попытается прочесть значение переменной B. Здесь и получается ошибка.
Необходимо инициализировать переменную B для случая s==0.